# Expecting a stackmap frame on java7 and tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, tomcat7, java-7

I'm trying to move my application from Java5/6 to Java7.
I can compile and publish the .war sucessfully. The problem is when i put the .war into the Tomcat7. I got the following stacktrace error:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webrun7]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 90 in method wfr.web.WebrunContextListener.contextInitialized(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContextEvent;)V at offset 0
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

Well, my class "WebrunContextListener" is really simple. It only implements the ServletContextListener, and when fired, it load some our own applications.

I use ant to generate my .war and the Eclipse as IDE.

Comment: The verifier needs information not present.  If you build with ant double check that you have debug information included.

Comment: It works correctly on eclipse... I'll check my ant debug info and i'll come back with more information.

Comment: Nothing useful on ant debug information... That's not a problem of ant i think.

Comment: Show relevant part of build.xml

Comment: <javac encoding="${output.encoding}" debug="true" target="${jre.version}" source="${jre.version}" destdir="${temp.dir.classes}" srcdir="${temp.dir.src}">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${classpath.j2ee}">
          <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${classpath.web.lib}">
          <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
      </classpath>
    </javac>

Comment: <target name="--dist-webrun">
    <war file="${dist.war}" basedir="${temp.dir.web}" />
    <move file="${dist.war}" todir="${dist.dir}" overwrite="true" />
  </target>

  <target name="--copy-to-webrun-version-folder">
    <antcall target="--create-webrun-version-folder" />
    <copy todir="${webrun.version.folder}" overwrite="true">
      <fileset file="${dist.dir}\${dist.war}" />
    </copy>
  </target>